# Angular 4 - Ngprime datatable sorting by many columns by default

Tags: angular, primeng-datatable

I am using ng prime Datatable for to work with tables.

This is my code html:

```
<p-dataTable #dt sortMode="multiple" [value]="registers" var="register">
    <p-column field="name" header="Name" [sortable]="true" sortBy="#{register.name}"></p-column>
    <p-column field="surname" header="Surname" [sortable]="true" sortBy="#{register.surname}"></p-column>
    <p-column field="datebirthday"  header="Date birthday" [sortable]="true" sortBy="#{register.datebirthday}"></p-column>
    <p-column field="phone" header="Phone" [sortable]="true"></p-column>
</p-dataTable>
```

I know like sort a one column by default:

```
<p-dataTable #dt sortField="datebirthday" sortOrder="-1"></p-dataTable>
```

But I need to order using many columns by default, but not working ok, in concret I need to sort by default for the next columns: name, surname and datebirthday.

How could resolve it?

Comment: I think you have to do it by your self, as it doesn't provide this functionality

Comment: ok I going to investigate another ways, maybe is better to sort in back end part, thanks

Comment: did u tried multiSortMeta property...for more detail refer https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable